# android broadcast receiver and service to get notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

hi i have used the following code in receiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("the time is right","yay!");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmServie.class);
        context.startService(i);
    }
 }
```

here i the code which i used in service class

```
public class AlarmServie extends Service {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.e("onStart:","came" );
     /*  NotificationManager notifyman = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent main_activity = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent o = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, main_activity, 0);

        /*Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder to Pill")
                .setContentText("Click for info")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(o)
                .build();*/
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent in = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getactivity(this, 0, in, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(AlarmServie.this);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Pill Reminder");
        mBuilder.setContentText("CLick here to View");
        //mBuilder.setSound(sound);

        TaskStackBuilder ts=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        ts.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        nm.notify(9999,mBuilder.build());

    }}
```

i created this code to get notification.when i run the app the receiver class is triggered but it is not moving to service class to invoke notification.can anyone say whats wrong in the code or say me how to get notification using broadcast receiver and service in a detailed tutorial

here is the manifest file and say me where to put the code exactly

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />



            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
        <activity android:name=".Set"></activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please explain in detail what the problem in code.please tell exactly where to put the service tag

Comment: Add service in manifeast.xml 
like:   <service android:name="Service Name" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"/>

Comment: Show us your Manifest file.

Comment: according to this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html Service lifecycle doesn't have a callback to onStart() method, writing your code in onCreate() could help I suppose

Comment: @Aniruddha i have uploaded the manifest file .tell me where to put the service tag exactly.i also tried it the app is forceclosing.

Comment: @KeerthivasanSelvarajan Check my answer. If it still crashes then post the error.

Comment: @Aniruddha now app is not crashing but receiver class is not pointing service class

Answer (score 0):

You must [declare service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) in manifest also. 
Intent to start service is sent to system then system tries to find right application component to handle this particular intent using information passed in manifest files.

It should be enough, but I'm not sure if you put service in the default package.

```
<application>
    ....
    <service android:name=".AlarmServie"/>
    ....
</application>
```

Comment: Piotrpo please tell me where to put the service tag.below the receiver tag or above application tag

Comment: can u say exactly where to put the service tag.and when I put it the app forecloses tell me y this happen

Comment: I've added the context. It would be helpful if you paste here error call stack in case of troubles.

Comment: @piotrpo09  -13 14:58:48.212 23085-23085/com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11 E/the time is right: yay!
09-13 14:58:48.218 23085-23085/com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11 D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { flg=0x114 cmp=com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11/.AlarmReceiver (has extras) } packageName=com.example.ashwin.pillreminder11 resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null} these are the errors i am getting after i put service tag the notification is not coming

Comment: is the above code is correct or else i have to change the servie class from onstart to  oncreate.if yes can u show me the code

Comment: @KeerthivasanSelvarajan, move all of your related `NotificationManager` stuff in `onStart` to `onStartCommand` callback instead, this method will be fired when the service starts.

Comment: @jan kaufmann can u change the above code with onstart and show

Comment: There's some misunderstanding on parts of your codes, like for example why would you start the service in broadcast receiver?, service would run first, and the broadcast receiver will be listening to this service it's communicating with. I think you can just explore how to construct broadcast receiver on some tutorial on the internet first.

Comment: @jan kaufmann so the entire code is wrong can u send  me the correct code

Comment: Looks like there is an error inside the service - so it's called now. @JanKaufmann - Starting service from BR is common practice as BR has strict maximum execution time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Your Manifest should look something like this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />



        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    //here is your service
     <service android:name=".AlarmServie" android:enabled="true"/>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
    <activity android:name=".Set"></activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```